# Not able to set OracleCommand.BindByName = true

Tags: c#, .net, oracle

I upgraded to Oracle 12.1 and from then my `OracleCommand` is not working. I am passing parameter like `cmd.Parameters["Name"].Value = username;` but getting exception as `Message envlink:System.IndexOutOfRangeException: Invalid index -1 for this OracleParameterCollection with Count=0`. I did some search and found to `OracleCommand.BindByName = true` but not able to find method `BindByName`. I am using `System.Data.OracleClient` version `4.0.0.0`.
How to resolve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, `Parameters` is collection. If you are trying to get element by key and is not exist - then you will get an `Invalid index` exception - you should add a parameter before trying to access to element with that name. Collection `Parameters` contains method `AddWithtValue` -

```
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("Name", username);
```

For example (`System.Data.OracleClient`):

```
        var con = new OracleConnection(source);
        using (con)
        {
            con.Open();
            using (var cmd = con.CreateCommand())
            {
                cmd.CommandText = "SELECT :NAME FROM dual";
                cmd.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.Text;
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("NAME", "Hello World!");

                using (var rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader())
                {
                    while (rdr.Read())
                    {
                        string val = rdr.GetString(0);
                        MessageBox.Show(val);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

But `System.Data.OraceClient` are deprecated and will not be supported by Microsoft. In the [ODP.Net](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/topics/dotnet/index-085163.html) you can add parameter with function `Add` (instead `AddWithtValue` how it is done in the `System.Data.OracleClient`):

```
cmd.Parameters.Add("Name", username);
```

or

```
cmd.Parameters.Add(
   new OracleParameter("Name", OracleDbType.Varchar2, username, ParameterDirection.Input)
);
```

for example (`ODP.Net`):

```
        using (OracleConnection con = new OracleConnection(source))
        {
            con.Open();
            using (var cmd = con.CreateCommand())
            {
                cmd.BindByName = true;
                cmd.CommandText = "select :NAME from dual";

                cmd.Parameters.Add("NAME", "Hello World!");
                /*
                command.Parameters.Add(
                  new OracleParameter("NAME", OracleDbType.Varchar2, "Hello World!", ParameterDirection.Input)
                 );
                */

                using (var rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader())
                {
                    while (rdr.Read())
                    {
                        string val = rdr.GetString(0);
                        MessageBox.Show(val);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: Updated with `cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("Name", username);` but getting exception like `ORA-06550: line 1, column 7:
PLS-00306: wrong number or types of arguments in call to 'ProcedureName'
ORA-06550: line 1, column 7:
PL/SQL: Statement ignored`

Comment: @Lara,  I added examples how to work with parameters. Show your code, if it does not work.

Comment: I am trying to open connectionstring like `conn = new OracleConnection(_conn);
    conn.Open();` but getting exception like `OracleConnection.ConnectionString is invalid`..How to resolve this?

Comment: Your should set correct ConnectionString. Look at [connectionstrings.com/oracle](https://www.connectionstrings.com/oracle/) for more information how to build it. "Omiting tnsnames.ora" will work perfectly as well.